# Measure the STD of RMSE

Tags: matlab, time-series, forecasting

I'm working on a time series forecasting problem and I would like to confirm if it makes sense to compute the standard deviation of the root mean squared error. If so, is this the correct way?

```
STD_test = std(sqrt((y_real-y_pred).^2))
```

Also, imagine that the output of the model is 100, the RMSE 20 and the STD 10. This means that the real value is between [70,120] ?

Comment: You're missing a ``mean`` in your definition of RMSE: ``sqrt(mean((y - yhat).^2))``. RMSE is thus a single numerical value, not an array. STD of that doesn't make any sense, but you could take the STD of your samples. Also, you can't conclude on the limits of your samples, only some information on their spread around the mean (i.e. STD of 10 = 68% of the samples are within +/- 10 units of your mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term `y_real-y_pred` is the vector of errors. The expression squares each element of it, and then sqrts each element of it, thus having the effect of `abs()`. Then `std()` is run on the vector of errors. Thus, this is computing the S.D. of the (absolute) error. That is a meaningful metric, but unlikely to be what you are after. Try:

```
e = y_real-y_pred;
MSE = mean(e.^2);
RMSE = sqrt(MSE);
sd = std(RMSE);
```

That will compute what you want. However, since RMSE is a scalar value, the value `sd` will be zero, so to answer the first part of your question, no it is not meaningful. What is meaningful is to look at the s.d. of the error itself:

```
sd = std(e);
```

RMSE and s.d. are somewhat related but they are distinct.

Comment: Part of me thought that it make no sense but the other part ... If RMSE = 15 mg/dl, we may say that there is an error associated with every predictions of ± 15 mg/dl, right?

Comment: Well, you can say that the RMSE is 15mg/dl, which means something precise. +- refers to a range, though it is sometimes used to indicate a scalar error metric such as s.d. or RMSE (in some arenas, it's not even erroneous to do that). However, I'd stick to reporting the exact metric you used.

Comment: What I would like to know is how can I interpret RMSE? It is the mean error associated with each prediction right? My data units is mg/dl that's why I used it ;)

Comment: RMSE is an order-2 error metric, versus an equivalent order-1 error metric which would be mean absolute error, say (MAE). RMSE is more sensitive to outliers, is one difference. In many fields, RMSE (or MSE) is used because it is very approachable using automated optimisation (automatic reduction of MSE is the most common optimisation technique there is, I would guess). For model/data analysis, either is good, and it depends a bit on the nature of the data (and of the analysis) which is more informative. In most cases, they will give you quite similar answers, semantically.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't really an answer. Roughly, the value of RMSE gives you an idea of the expected value of an error on any one sample, yes. At least, for zero-mean Gaussian data. The most precise description of what RMSE means, is that it is the RMSE. However, and at the risk of being burned at the stake by a passing statistician, its value can be interpreted as a guide to the error magnitude, for many problems derived from physical systems (which, as we all know, are all zero-mean and Gaussian...).

Answer (score 0):

Your RMSE is fine; but the final conclusion is not! A std of 10 means there's a roughly 68% chance that your output lies within +- std. You can refer to [this wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) to learn more about the rule.

Comment: BTW, your RMSE gives the error of _each element of your series_. If you're looking for a single number to represent the RMSE of the whole series, you have to take the mean as Sebastien mentions.

Comment: I know that the mean is missing for the rmse function but like you said with the mean there I would get a scalar. That's why I took it from the formula.